# How can you set up the simulation to hold agents from entering the process until the agent ahead is through and out of the process?

Tags: queue

Setting up an aviation simulation for flight patterns and need to prevent the second agent from entering the pattern until the first is completely through the entire process.

I have tried the wait, delay, and queue but may not have them set up correctly. I would also appreciate some help on how to set up these elements